# Trying to upload image on Laravel Ubuntu Nginx Server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I just deployed my laravel project on Nginx Ubuntu Server but anytime i tried to upload image i get this error

```
2020-06-14 21:00:32] production.ERROR: fopen(/var/www/laravel/public/image/uploads/1.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(/var/www/laravel/public/image/uploads/1.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied at /var/www/laravel/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php:157)
```

and also in my database i get this `/tmp/phpuFp8xC`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you have access to command line, give `public` 777 permission level with this command `chmod -R 777 public`  ensure you are in the Laravel project root folder

Comment: Getting this error now```2020-06-14 21:13:07] production.ERROR: URI must be a string or UriInterface (View: /var/www/laravel/resources/views/pages/welcome.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): URI must be a string or UriInterface (View: /var/www/laravel/resources/views/pages/welcome.blade.php) at /var/www/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php:62) ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in config/filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path(), // previously storage_path();
],]
```

Comment: I am getting this error now ```2020-06-14 21:13:07] production.ERROR: URI must be a string or UriInterface (View: /var/www/laravel/resources/views/pages/welcome.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): URI must be a string or UriInterface (View: /var/www/laravel/resources/views/pages/welcome.blade.php) at /var/www/laravel/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php:62) ```